# intent-filter を指定した Activity が起動しない

Tags: android

Android Studio の開発ではまってます

Activity１　Activity２　Activity３ と３つの Activity があり
Activity１ からメニューアイテムで Activity２ と　Activity３ を明示的インテントで起動します
マニフェストで Activity１ に Intent-filter を記述してあるのですが、Android Studio からエミュレータを起動すると Activity２ が起動します
アプリを一度終了して、エミュレータのアイコンから起動すると、ちゃんと Activity1 から起動します

試しに Activity3 に Intent-filter を移動して Android Studio から起動しても、やはり Activity2 が起動します

Android Studio の設定がおかしいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: AndroidManifest.xmlを載せてもらえないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アプリの実行構成（Run/Debug Configurations）の Activity が Launch Default Activity ではなく、Launch（Activity2） になってました

Comment: 解決したならチェックマークを押して解決したことにしてください。